# jQuery UI autocomplete - matched option not getting selected on focusOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have made a **`jQuery UI - autocomplete`** in which I have added the following conditions:

1. Sorted option list
2. mandatory select an option

Here I made a mistake that, when I type the exact option, it is not getting selected.

**For example:**

```
var json = ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC", "ALASKA", "MADERA", "ANDERSON", 
                                                  "Kingston", "Kala", "Aka"];
```

> 1. I type **`aka`**, it is *not accepting*.
> 2. I also tried **`Aka`**, still it is *not accepting*.

**How to reproduce:**

> After typing the *above text* in `textbox`, just `focusout` - The value
>   will be emptied.  I want to handle **`aka = Aka = AKA`** *(with/without selecting from option list)*

**PS:** I'm not asking for code, I have made a small blunder which I need it to be correct.

Here is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/17/), where you can easily reproduce the exception.

How can I change my code to work like this.  Please share your suggestions and point me in a right direction on placing the conditions in order.

Comment: Based on the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) your fiddle is working fine. Could you explain more what you think it should be doing that is different to the example I provided?

Comment: @Reigel in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/17/) if you type `aka` or `Aka` and focusout without selecting it from the dropdown list. Then you can see the textbox getting empty.  But it I want don't want this thing to be happened.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Nunners Sure, I have customized the autocomplete in my fiddle.  In order to satisfy my condition.  Please go through my above comments.  Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

What if you change the event to close instead of the change event. Then check if the value is in the array and if not clear the container. This will require you match capitalization when you enter the value. If you wanted to ignore capitalization you could do a convert the json array to lower case and the value to lowercase before search the array.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j576p/5/)

```
var json = ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC", "ALASKA", "MADERA", "ANDERSON", "Kingston", "Kala", "Aka"];
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var matches = $.map(json, function (json) {
            if (json.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0) {
                return json;
            }
        });
        response(matches);
    },

    close: function(event, ui) {
        var index = jQuery.inArray($('input').val(), json);
        if (index == -1) {
            $('input').val("");           
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) the UI property only gets set when a dropdown item is selected (clicked on) so you will have to add to your validation in the change function to manually check against the values.